# React page does not show changes after saving and deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, npm, mongoose

I am developing an application over a few weeks now. Suddenly today, if i change anything (and save it) - even just a word in the header or a console.log() - , the change is not shown in the browser but otherwise it runs just perfectly. I already deployed again and tried deleting the package.json and nodes_module and installing them again.

I know this is really vague, but maybe one of you has an idea.. I would be really grateful.

I am using:
Visual Studio Code
Windows 11
Google Chrome

Comment: Ah and i deployed on localhost!

Comment: did u tried to refresh browser when you make changes

Comment: yes i did, and also tried to delete cache and cookies